# Gitlab runner docker host setting

Tags: docker, gitlab

How should i enter the "host" value for the host params?

https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runners-section

Thanks in advance!

I tried tcp://0.0.0.0:2375, 0.0.0.0:2375, 0.0.0.0, etc and all result in errors.

```
[runners.docker]
    host = tcp://0.0.0.0:2375
    tls_verify = false
    image = "docker:latest"
```

The runner toml config file should be accepted without any error

Comment: Did you see [this](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/docker.html)?

Comment: Don't see anything on this page that applies to my issue.... Is there something i am missing out?

Answer (score 0):

You should leave it blank, if you run the command on your PC.

The format is 'ip-address:port-number'.

You can set the value of the host to 127.0.0.1:2375

```
[runners.docker]
    host=127.0.0.1:2375
```